# Show Images via Dropdown dynamically

Tags: assets, drop-down

I am currently working with craft.

I want to create a `filter` with a dropdown list that will only display the images, that are related to the selected dropdown.

Is that even possible?

What I have:

```
<div class="row">
    <select>
        {% for option in entry.selection.options %}
            <option>{{ option.value }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    {% for image in entry.bild %}
        <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
            <a data-fancybox="gallery-{{entry.slug}}" href="{{ image.url }}"><img width="100%" src="{{ image.url }}"></a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: We need more information how they are related? What values does the dropdown contain? Is is a size range? A related category? a date range picker? Does it has to do with the filename? (eg beginning character A, B, C)

Comment: The image will have a value which was added to the image by field. See Screenshot [My Screenshot](https://imgur.com/KKpq93t).
The dropdown will have values like years and months (my intention was to create 2 dropdown menus and sort the images like that)

At the end it should only loop the images with like the same year: For example i will select "2017", and all images that have the selection "2017" will display

Comment: Do you want to load them dynamically via ajax or during the page reload?

Comment: Best would be via Ajax, but if its simplier to use page reload than I would choose this.